# magento 2 : getting shipping rates table data

Tags: shipping, magento-2.1, geoip

Iam having shipping rate data in database table.

```
    Country Region  Zip Code    Order  (and above)  Shipping Price
      IN       *        *          0                     45
      IN       *        *          25                    50
      IN       *        *          50                    55
      IN       *        *          76                    60
      US      AK        *          0                    100
      US      NY        *          51                   110
      US      CA        *         101                   120
      US      FL        *         151                   130
```

How to get data based on country with ip address.I want to show it in product page tab